# bindToController in angular1.2 directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there a way I can inject the feature `bindToController` in an angular 1.2 directive. I know it exist in angular 1.3 +. But I am stuck with angular 1.2 and I need this feature so that I can make my code more aligned with angular 2 (by ignoring $scope)

Thanks.

Comment: down voter comment ?

Comment: Not downvoter but I'm not sure you would want to do this. I get what you are trying to achieve, but it's not part of the library you are using locally, you could possibly bring in the chunk of code that is bindToController, but you have no idea what changed from 1.2 to 1.3 that it might depend on or break your own code. Just my thoughts.

Comment: No. This is integral part of `$compile` that is hard to polyfill and easy to break. When $scope is rarely used, 1.2 app isn't a bit more closer to Angular 2. Switch to later Angular version. Use 1.5 with components and ng-forward for this purpose.